# How to kill slave kernel securely?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

`LinkClose[link]` "does not necessarily terminate the program at the other end
of the connection" as it is said in the Documentation. Is there a way to kill the
process of the slave kernel securely?

**EDIT:**

In really I need a function in *Mathematica* that returns only when the process of the slave kernel has already killed and its memory has already released. Both `LinkInterrupt[link, 1]` and `LinkClose[link]` do not wait while the slave kernel exits. At this moment the only such function is seemed to be `killProc[procID]` function I had showed in one of answers at this page. But is there a built-in analog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment I know only one method to kill the `MathKernel` process securely. This method uses `NETLink` and seems to work only under Windows and requires Microsoft .NET 2 or later to be installed.

```
killProc[processID_] := If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows",
   Needs["NETLink`"];
   Symbol["LoadNETType"]["System.Diagnostics.Process"];
   With[{procID = processID},
    killProc[procID_] := (
       proc = Process`GetProcessById[procID];
       proc@Kill[]
       );
    ];
   killProc[processID]
   ];
(*Killing the current MathKernel process*)
killProc[$ProcessID]
```

Any suggestions or improvements will be appreciated.

### Edit:

The more correct method:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
LoadNETType["System.Diagnostics.Process"];

$kern = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink -noinit"];
LinkRead[$kern];
LinkWrite[$kern, Unevaluated[$ProcessID]];
$kernProcessID = First@LinkRead[$kern];
$kernProcess = Process`GetProcessById[$kernProcessID];

AbortProtect[If[! ($kernProcess@Refresh[]; $kernProcess@HasExited),
  $kernProcess@Kill[]; $kernProcess@WaitForExit[];
  $kernProcess@Close[]];
 LinkClose[$kern]]
```

### Edit 2:

Even more correct method:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
LoadNETType["System.Diagnostics.Process"];

$kern = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink -noinit"];
LinkRead[$kern];
LinkWrite[$kern, Unevaluated[$ProcessID]];
$kernProcessID = First@LinkRead[$kern];
$kernProcess = Process`GetProcessById[$kernProcessID];

krnKill := AbortProtect[
   If[TrueQ[MemberQ[Links[], $kern]], LinkClose[$kern]];
   If[TrueQ[MemberQ[LoadedNETObjects[], $kernProcess]],
    If[! TrueQ[$kernProcess@WaitForExit[100]],
     Quiet@$kernProcess@Kill[]; $kernProcess@WaitForExit[]];
    $kernProcess@Close[]; ReleaseNETObject[$kernProcess];
    ]
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Todd Gayley has answered my question in the newsgroup. The solution is to send to the slave kernel an `MLTerminateMessage`. From 
top-level code:

```
   LinkInterrupt[link, 1] (* An undocumented form that lets you pick 
the message type *)
```

In C:

```
   MLPutMessage(link, MLTerminateMessage);
```

In Java using J/Link:

```
   link.terminateKernel();
```

In .NET using .NET/Link:

```
   link.TerminateKernel();
```

**EDIT:**

I have discovered that in standard cases when using `LinkInterrupt[link, 1]`
my operating system (Windows 2000 at the moment) releases physical memory
only in 0.05-0.1 second beginning with a moment of execution of
`LinkInterrupt[link, 1]` while with `LinkClose[link]` it releases physical
memory in 0.01-0.03 second (both values include the time, spent on execution
of the command itself). Time intervals were measured by using `SessionTime[]`
under equal conditions and are steadily reproduced.

Actually I need a function in *Mathematica* that returns only when the process of the slave kernel has already killed and its memory has already released. Both `LinkInterrupt[link, 1]` and `LinkClose[link]` do not wait while the slave kernel exits. At this moment the only such function is seemed to be `killProc[procID]` function I had showed in another answer at this page.