# I have a 64 bit OS but Mathematica does not finish evaluation

Tags: memory, wolfram-mathematica, allocation, cap

I've been having problems with the way mathematica evaluates my integral. It is a multiple integral with the outer integral being a countour integral. When I press "Shift + Enter" to run mathematica, it says that it is running but after some time it stops evaluating and does not give any output.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854980/correct-way-to-cap-mathematica-memory-use) the post says that on a 64-bit OS, Mathematica will freely use all the memory available and grind the system to a halt while in a 32-bit OS, the maximum memory allocated to any one program is limited.

Although I have a 64-bit OS, I tried using `MemoryConstrained` placed a 1 gig cap but Mathematica still stops the evaluation without giving any result. And when I check the memory used during evaluation using `MaxMemoryUsed[]`, Mathematica did not even reach the 1 gig memory cap.

What are the possible sources of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. For reference, here is a picture of the specs of my computer 
[image]

Comment: you should go to mathematica.stackexchange.com, but note you aren't going to get anywhere without showing the integral.

Comment: I cant show the integral because of some particular reasons. Sorry about that. However for some values of the parameters, say $x$ Mathematiica gives an output. When I increase the value of $x$ I encounter the problem above.

Comment: MMA can have the computational kernel quit and bail out on you without being particularly obvious. If you open your notebook and click on Evaluation in the menu bar and slide your mouse down to Quit Kernel then you should see Local. If you click on that it will ask if you are sure and you can say yes to stop the kernel. BUT if you do these exact same steps after your integral has stopped then the Local will likely be grey and not respond to clicks which means the kernel bailed. That doesn't tell you why. Can you get each inner integral to complete? Can you try a similar simpler inner integral?